# Detecting Touches in an OpenGL rendered scene

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, touch

I was wondering whether there is a way to detect a touch in an OpenGL rendered scene. What I have i a set of images which are being rendered in my main view. Now if the user touches one of these images (or objects) I would like to know which one was touched - similar to the

```
CGRectContainsPoint(frame, [touch locationInView:self.view]
```

method.

Is there an easy way to find out? If there is none, this would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [picking and selecting FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm). This of course assumes that you do indeed have a full-blown OpenGL implementation, I don't think that the OpenGL ES spec (for instance) includes selection support.